# Epoll wont rebuild on raspberry pi3 using election forge

Tags: raspberry-pi3, epoll, electron-forge

I have electron forge installed on my rpi3.  I am trying to build an electron app that uses the module ‘onoff’ to access the GPIO pins.  When I try to build the app using ‘npm run make’ i get the following error.

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: node-gyp failed to rebuild '/home/pi/Documents/pi-console/node_modules/epoll'
at ChildProcess. (/home/pi/Documents/pi-console/node_modules/@electron/rebuild/lib/module-type/node-gyp/node-gyp.js:118:24)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)

I have tried everything from using electron-rebuild, to changing node to 16.16.0 and nothing is working.  I can use ‘one-off’ on the rpi when i run some node code that controls a GPIO pin so I know that ‘onoff’ can install.  The issue seems to be the rebuild of ‘epoll’ but I dont understand it good enough to debug as I am new to electron and inexperienced in node.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.